# Serving UI in express.js after logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I understand how to return a file using express with:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'fileName.html'))
```

And I understand how to serve up a folder using:

```
app.use('/customAPI', express.static('folderName'));
```

using the documentation [here.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)

The folder with the UI is created using angular 4 build. So, it all goes into one folder creating a `index.html` and a bunch of `*.bundle.html` files.
However, I don't understand how to serve up a the UI after doing some logic. For example:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    let myParam = req.query.whatever;
    if (whatever) {
        res.redirect('//google.com'); //this works fine
    }
    else {
        //I don't know what to do here
        app.use("/somePath", 'dist'); //won't work because what do I put in "somePath"?
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/index.html')); 
        //^ this only serves up the file but fails because it can't find the library files that index.html needs to load.
    }
});
```

I've tried going down the road of trying to use res.render but I'm not 100% sure if that is what I'm looking for.

**Question**: How do I serve up a folder containing all ui information correctly

Comment: `app.user()` ? shouldn't that be `app.use()`

Answer (score 0):

When you serve a specific path these are sending the content only for that path, for example an HTML with the interface, the HTML file can make calls to other files, like CSS, JS etc ...

You need to [serve the static files in a public folder](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

All files in the `static` folder will be served in the url `/static/filename`

In the html of the path, you must include the resources of the `static` folder that you need

Comment: but can I use that app.use inside this else statement? how do i return with the res object?

Comment: no, you cant use app.use inside the route, you need to use in the main configuration, app.use serve a folder.

Comment: Got it, more or less. It may be a hack, but what I'm doing in the else statement is `res.redirect` to the path I'm using for the `app.use`. Also, like you said i need to put the path in front of any of the resources in the `index.html` that it is trying to load